# Inheriting from Array class

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

All arrays i  create in C# inherit implicitly from the Array class. So why are methods like Sort() etc not available to the array i create.
For example, consider the following code:

```
int [] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};

Console.WriteLine(arr.Length); //This works,Length property inherited from Array

Array.Sort(arr); //Works

arr.Sort(); //Incorrect !
```

Please Help
Thank You.

Comment: There are loads of reasons... you cannot inherit an Array for example, what do you mean with 'implicitly' here?

Comment: Fall in the pit of success kinda feature, I think.  An array does *not* know how to sort itself.

Answer (score 12):

It's because the [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc.aspx) method is a static method defined on the Array class so you need to call it like this:

```
Array.Sort(yourArray);
```

You don't need an instance of the class to call a static method. You directly call it on the class name. In OOP there's no notion of inheritance for static methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So static methods are not inherited. Any particular reason for that ?.Also,can static data members be inherited ?

Comment: @Joe: It's not so much that they're not inherited as that you don't call them "on" an instance. In this case you happen to *supply* an instance to the method, but that's effectively a coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

`Sort` is a static method on the `Array` class, that's why you call it using `Array.Sort()`. When you try `arr.Sort()`, you're trying to access an instance method which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use an extension method to add a Sort function as an instance member of the Array type.

```
public static class ArrayExtension
{
    public static void Sort(this Array array)
    {
        Array.Sort(array);
    }
}
```

Example

```
int [] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
arr.Sort();
```

DISCLAIMER: I have not compiled and tried this, but I am pretty sure that it will work.

Comment: I wonder why they haven't modified their Array.Sort signature in the first place when they where introducing ExtensionMethods. Old code using the static version still would compile and as it is syntactic sugar which the compiler handles, existing binaries shouldn't be affected. (Although this would mean adding an ArrayExtensions class or relaxing the "non-generic, non-nested, static class" constraint for Extensions)

Answer (score 1):

Array.Sort() is a static method so you won't see it hanging off instances. However, you can use the OrderBy() extension method on any IEnumerable to do what you are seeking.

Comment: OrderBy doesn't sort an array internally; it creates a separate (but sorted) sequence. This is not the same thing.

Comment: @Marc - you are absolutely correct. I was just trying to give him an alternative to meet his goal after I explained the static method aspect. Thanks.